# How to load a local json file in Xcode for unit test purposes?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, unit-testing

So I have added the file `testJson1.json` to my project.

Within the unit test I have tried to get the filepath without any luck:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *filepath = [bundle pathForResource:@"testJson1.json" ofType:@"json"];
```

When I look at the project file, I can oddly enough see that the file is added to the resources, I thought unit test files would not be added to the resource to keep the app size down.

```
8AA238811C5565E80031648E /* testJson1.json in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 8AA2387F1C5565E80031648E /* testJson1.json */; };
```

What am I missing please?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your file has checked `iTagNewsTests` target in `Target Membership` in `File inspector` (first tab in right panel).

Comment: Could it be because the extra `.json` in the resource name is not needed?  That is try `[bundle pathForResource:@"testJson1" ofType:@"json"]`?

Comment: @alfigueroa yep that was it. So silly of me. :) Feel free to add the answer

Comment: @Houman Sure, in case anyone skips the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the `.json` from the resource name as this is not needed :)

`NSString *filepath = [bundle pathForResource:@"testJson1" ofType:@"json"];`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a Test class from the above picture named...

```
final class TagNewsTests: XCTestCase {
```

In your func test() method load the bundle this way...

```
let url = Bundle(for: TagNewsTests.self).url(forResource: "testJson1", withExtension: "json")
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this:

`let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: ".json")
 guard let dataURL = url, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataURL) else { 
     fatalError("Couldn't read data.json file") }`

The difference is that I marked the extension with `.json` instead of just `json`

Comment: Bundle.main.url will NOT work if your JSON files are in your "Tests" project as supporting files.